# WPF - Binding a TabControl's Itemsource to Single Object

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, itemtemplate

I have a Wpf DatarGrid which is bound to a List of Customers . Here  , what I want is that when I select one customer in datagrid and click on an Update Button , an window opens . This new window has a tab control. then second time when I click on update for another User in the datagrid , second tab should open in this already opened new window. To achieve this I want to bind Tab control to only Selected Customer row and not to an ObservableCollection or a List . But when I bind SelectedCustomer to the Itemssource property , its not working as header is coming blank. For the header , I have an Itemtemplate , inside which a textblock is bound to a property of the SelectedCustomer like name .

What is the solution to this?

My data grid looks like this  -

```
<DataGrid Width="700" Height="500" Margin="20" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Margin="5" Click="Update_Clicked">Update</Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Margin="5">Delete</Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Here you can see the selecteditem property is bound to a SelectedCustomer . Now the tab control window looks like this  -

```
 <TabControl Name="UserTabs" ItemsSource="{Binding}">


            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="TabItem">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="226"  Margin="4">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">First Name :</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Last Name :</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">Email Address :</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"><Hyperlink>Address :</Hyperlink></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4">City :</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding EmailAddress}"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding City}"></TextBox>


                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">State :</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"><Hyperlink>Orders :</Hyperlink></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding State}"></TextBox>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5"></TextBlock>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

        </TabControl>
```

As you can see I have used Itemssource = {Binding} , meaning that Itemssource is bound to SelectedCustomer , because in code behind I have set

```
this.datacontext = SelectedCustomer
```

And then in ItemTemplate and Content Template  , bound textblocks and textboxes to properties of the SelectedCustomer using

```
{Binding <PropertyName>}
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample code? I think, your problem is related to tab control or you want to redesign it?

Comment: So to clarify, selecting a row should open a new window the first time, and a single tab in a `TabControl` is created in this window, and when another row is selected you want to create a second tab in the previously created window and select this new tab?

Comment: @Gui - correct . So these tab controls will be showing details of the Customer selected in the Datagrid . So the datacontext or itemssource of the TabControl should be this single selected Customer . This value I have as a property in a viewmodel . And it is passed into the constructor of the new Window/ new tab( depending on if the window is already open) . But when I bind tab control's itemssource to this passed value  , then the Header and Content do not show those values, they only get bound properly when it's an Observable collection.

Comment: @Sham - I have edited question and put in the code .

Comment: You could use a converter to turn your tuple into a collection with one  child, but this isn't going to work the way you describe. Hypothetically, you select the first customer, and a new window is opened, and the customer is presented in your `TabControl`, when you select the second customer, the `SelectedItem` property will change, and the `TabControl` won't have any knowledge of the first item. How can it maintain this tab if it is out of context?

Comment: I think what you will need is some sort of management around your `TabControl`. EG when you select a line in your `DataGrid` it pushes that entry to another collection which is then shown in your `TabControl`. When this collection is updated, its selection should also update to the latest item added, or something to that effect.

Comment: @Gui - so , the plan regarding how to handle selected customer when same one is selected later is if the tab is already open ,it should focus back to that  tab and If not open, new tab. But I understand , what you are saying conceptually is correct and I need to think in a different way. Maybe a Collection of Selected Customers to bind to Tab Control , and then check whether newly selected customer is already in that list . Only Problem with that I wanted this Tab Control to be lot more complex , like when I click on Create New from Window 1 , an empty form should open in that second window .

Comment: @GameFromScratch so with this in mind; it might be worth updating your question?